# How can you start two chrome windows with different WM_CLASS attributes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

I want to start two isolated chrome windows, with each their own `WM_CLASS` property set.

For the first window, I do:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --class test-1 --new-window
```

Running `xprop`, I notice that this has been set correctly:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "google-chrome", "test-1"
```

Now I do the same for the second window:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --class test-2 --new-window
```

I get in `prop` for that second window:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "google-chrome", "test-1"
```

So for the second window, the `WM_CLASS` from the first window is taken.

How can I fix this?

To give some context, these `WM_CLASS` attributes will be used in a `i3wm` environment to move the windows in question to dedicated workspace. There doesn't seem to be another way to do this, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug-report for this problem:
[Issue 118613: The --class argument is ignored unless using --user-data-dir](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118613).

This bug has been fixed and then lately re-appeared again.

Until it is fixed again, probably the previous workaround of using different
`--user-data-dir` folders for each Chrome instance will still work.

Comment: Thank you. I can see the `--user-data-dir` workaround working, but does that mean I will lose my profiles, configurations, cookies, ... when I define another one?

Comment: You will need to duplicate the profile. You could also try to revive that bug report (small chances).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the feedback!